# How to catch exceptions thrown by the ConnectAsync method of MessageWebSocket?

Tags: c++, websocket, uwp

I'm implementing an UWP application for the HoloLens which streams a point cloud over a `MessageWebSocket` to a companion PC. If I launch the app on the HoloLens while the server on the companion PC is not yet running, calling the `ConnectAsync` method of `MessageWebSocket` triggers an exception (because it can't connect to the server) which causes my app to crash. However, I can't figure out how to catch this exception.

Inspired by the example code shown in the [official documentation of MessageWebSocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/networking/websockets#use-messagewebsocket-to-connect), this is a small sample which reproduces the issue:

```
void TryConnectToWebsocket()
{
    Windows::Networking::Sockets::MessageWebSocket^ websocket = ref new Windows::Networking::Sockets::MessageWebSocket();
    websocket->Control->MessageType = Windows::Networking::Sockets::SocketMessageType::Utf8;

    try
    {
        ::OutputDebugString(L"Trying to connect...\n");
        auto connectTask = Concurrency::create_task(websocket->ConnectAsync(ref new Windows::Foundation::Uri(L"ws://192.168.0.38:9090")));
        connectTask.then([this, websocket]
        {
            ::OutputDebugString(L"Connected successfully!");
            websocket->Close(1000, "Application caused the connection to close.");
        });
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        ::OutputDebugString(L"Couldn't connect to websocket!");
    }
}
```

Please note, that the original example code from the docs catches exceptions of type `Platform::Exception`. I chose to catch exceptions of all types in this code snippet to assert that I don't miss the exception in case it is not a `Platform::Exception` (or a subtype of it).

If I run this code snippet (without the server being started), I would expect the following console output:

```
Trying to connect...
Couldn't connect to the websocket!
```

However, what I get is the following: (Console outputs about loaded and unloaded DLLs have been left out. Some of the messages describing what went wrong were originally in German, so I've translated them.)

```
Trying to connect...
Exception thrown at 0x76B34592 (KernelBase.dll) in Test.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80072EFD : 'A connection with the server could not be established.'.
Exception thrown at 0x76B34592 in Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x0C5AE500. HRESULT:0x80072EFD The message for this error code could not be found.
WinRT information: A connection with the server could not be established.
Stack trace:
 >[External Code]
```

As you can see, the catch block isn't being executed at all. Furthermore, the very short and unprecise stack trace makes it appear as if the exception is thrown somewhere in a background thread where I don't even have a chance of catching it.

I'd really like to handle this exception instead of having the application crash. Is there any way how I can do this?

Comment: By testing, I can reproduce this issue, but except the error, I also skipped to "No Symbol Loaded" page, do you have the same behavior?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I added the Microsoft Symbol Servers as a symbol file location for debugging in Visual Studio (which can be done at Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols). Therefore, I don't see that "No Symbols Loaded" page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebSocket/cpp), it doesn't put every operation that might throw within a try…catch block. Instead, it adds a task-based continuation at the end of the chain and handles all errors there. You can try the following code to catch the exception.

```
create_task(messageWebSocket->ConnectAsync(ref new Windows::Foundation::Uri(L"ws://192.168.0.38:9090")))
        .then([this](task<void> previousTask)
            {
                try
                {
                    previousTask.get();
                    ::OutputDebugString(L"Connected successfully!");
                    websocket->Close(1000, "Application caused the connection to close.");
                }
                catch (Exception^ ex)
                {
                    ::OutputDebugString(L"Couldn't connect to websocket!");
                }

            });
```

Comment: This solved the issue. Thank you so much for your help :)